# Manifest.json extensión Chrome auto fill

Tags: extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una extensión de autocompletar formularios en Chrome, para poder manipular los valores de los inputs de los formularios tengo pensado hacerlo a través de un archivo javascript con múltiples algoritmos, pero para poder manipular los inputs de las otras páginas a través del javascript de la extensión obviamente deben estar enlazados, para hacer eso se hacen las declaraciones en el manifest.json:

```
 "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["http://www.página_web.com/"], "js":
 ["myscript.js"], "run_at": "document_end" }]
```

Pero como serían muchísimas páginas web en la que el usuario haría uso de la extensión y uno como desarrollador no sabe cuales serian, mi pregunta es:

> ¿Hay alguna forma dinámica(programable) de manipular el manifest.json 
>   en donde pueda enlazar diferentes páginas web con mi javascript?
>
> O ¿hay alguna manera de enlazar las páginas web que vista el usuario
>   con mi js mientras hace uso de mi extensión?